# Storing Int64 in UserDefaults

Tags: xcode, swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I define my dictionary like this:

```
var teamsData = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Int64>>()
```

Then, I am trying to store it in userdefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(teamsData, forKey: "teamsData")
```

but it throws the error:

```
Type Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Int64>> does not conform to protocol 'Any Object'
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A user default object can only be an instance (or a combination of
instances) of
 `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray`, or `NSDictionary`.

Some Swift types are automatically bridged to Foundation types,
e.g. `Int`, `UInt`, `Float`, `Double` and `Bool` are bridged
to `NSNumber`. So this could be saved in the user defaults:

```
var teamsData = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,Int>>()
```

On 64-bit architectures, `Int` *is* a 64-bit integer, but on
32-bit architectures, `Int` is a 32-bit integer.

The fixed-sized integer types such as `Int64` are *not*
automatically bridged to `NSNumber`. This was also observed
in [Swift - Cast Int64 to AnyObject for NSMutableArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305855/swift-cast-int64-to-anyobject-for-nsmutablearray).
Therefore, to store 64-bit integers in the user defaults you have
to use `NSNumber` explicitly:

```
var teamsData = Dictionary<String,Dictionary<String,NSNumber>>()

// Example how to add a 64-bit value:
let value : UInt64 = 123
teamsData["foo"] = ["bar" : NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: value)]
```

Answer (score 17):

Martin's answer is no longer correct for Swift 3 since the set function is now type `Any?` instead of `AnyObject?`.

You can store an Int64 in UserDefaults like so:

```
import Foundation
let value: Int64 = 1000000000000000
UserDefaults.standard.set(value, forKey: "key")
if let value2 = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "key") as? Int64 {
    // value2 is an Int64 with a value of 1000000000000000
    print(value2)
}
```

You can paste the above code into a Swift playground and try yourself.

Comment: Have you ever gotten a SIGABRT error from using this?

Comment: I haven't. What version of Swift are you using?

Comment: 3.0, I believe. I'm using Int for now, hopefully it works before I run out of 32-bit integers...

Comment: Weird, I definitely haven't seen the crash. One other option is to store it as a string and then just convert to/from integer when you do the user defaults writes/reads. Not ideal, but if it's crashing on you that's an option that will work for any length integer.

Answer (score 7):

Swift 4:

You can save int64 as string in UserDefaults

```
let value: Int64 = 1000000000000000
let stringValue = String(value)
UserDefaults.standard.set(stringValue, forKey: "int64String")
```

Like that you avoid Int truncation.

And then you can recover the original value:

```
let int64String = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "int64String")
let originalValue = Int64(int64String!)
```

This allow you to compare it with other int64 values