# UInt64 in an NSDictionary

Tags: ios, swift, 32bit-64bit

I have an unsigned 63-bit value that I store in a UInt64 that I need to convert to an AnyObject so I can store it in a NSDictionary. I have converted it to an Int, but that will only store it on a 64-bit system, on a 32-bit system an Int is still 32-bit and I get an error. Since neither UInt64 nor Int64 can be cast to an AnyObject, I cannot use them. Do I have better options than `NSNumber(unsignedlonglong: value)`

Comment: "Do I have better options than NSNumber(unsignedlonglong: value)" Better how?

Comment: There is no better option, compare http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28177435/storing-int64-in-userdefaults.

Comment: Sorry for being vague, with "better" I meant more Swift-native less Cocoa-dependant, but since it's going into an NSDictionary, this is probably not relevant

Comment: more Swift-native less Cocoa-dependant .... so why you use the NSDictionary as 'storage' container?

Comment: Even an Int is converted to NSNumber when you put it into an NSDictionary, the only difference is that the compiler creates the code for you.

Comment: Thanks guys, I'll stick with NSNumber then :-)