# Does UserDefaults.integer work on 32-bit platforms?

Tags: swift, int, nsuserdefaults

Will the following code work on 32-bit platforms?

```
class Account {
  private static let UserIDKey = "AccountUserIDKey"
  class var userID: Int64? {
    get { Int64(UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserIDKey)) }
    set { UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: UserIDKey) }
  }
}
```

Ie, will it work on 32-bit platforms if I store and retrieve an `Int` value that's greater than `Int32.max` into `UserDefaults`?

I'm wondering because I only see the `UserDefaults` instance method `integer(forKey:)`. Why doesn't `UserDefaults` have an instance method like `int64(forKey:)`?

Answer (score -2):

You can save a number of simple variable types in the user defaults:

- `Booleans` with `Bool`
- `integers` with `Int`
- `floats` with `Float`
- `doubles` with `Double`
- `Strings` with `String`
- `binary` data with `Data`
- `dates` with `Date`
- `URLs` with the `URL` type
- `Collection` types with `Array` and `Dictionary`

  > Internally the UserDefaults class can only store `NSData`, `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDate`, `NSArray` and `NSDictionary` classes.

  *These are object types that can be saved in a property list.*

An `NSNumber` is an `NSObject` that can contain the original C style numeric types, which even include the `C/Objective-C` style `BOOL` type (that stores `YES` or `NO`). Thankfully for us, these are also bridged to Swift, so for a Swift program, an `NSNumber` can automatically accept the following Swift types:

- UInt
- Int
- Float
- Double
- Bool

---

***[Dmitry Popov's answer in Quora](https://www.quora.com/How-is-a-UInt64-represented-in-a-32-bit-device-Swift-2-0)***

> Remember how you were taught in school how to add numbers like 38 and 54. You work with separate digits. You take rightmost digits, 8 and 4, add them, get the digit 2 in answer and 1 carried because of an overflow. You take the second digits, 3 and 5, add them to get 8 and add the carried 1 to get result 9, so the whole answer becomes 92. A 32-bit processor does exactly the same, but instead of decimal digits it's got 32-bit integers, algorithms are the same: work on two 32-bit parts of 64-bit number separately, deal with overflows by carrying from lower to higher word. This takes several 32-bit instructions and the compiler is responsible to encode them properly.

---

**Save `Int64` to `UserDefaults`**

```swift
import Foundation

let defaults = UserDefaults.standart

//Define an 64bit integer with `Int64`
let myInteger: Int64 = 1000000000000000

//Save the integer to `UserDefaults`
defaults.set(myInteger, forKey: "myIntegerKey")

// Get the saved value from `UserDefaults`
guard let savedInteger = defaults.object(forKey: "myIntegerKey") as? Int64 else { return }

print("my 64bit integer is:", savedInteger)
```

---

**Save 64bit `Int` to `UserDefaults` via converting to `String`**

```swift
let myInteger: Int64 = 1000000000000000
let myString = String(myInteger)

//Save the `myString` to `UserDefaults`
UserDefaults.standard.set(myString, forKey: "myIntegerKey")


// Get the value from `UserDefaults`
let myString = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "myIntegerKey")
let myInteger = Int64(myString!)
```

---

**Resources**

- [How is a `UInt64` represented in a 32 bit device](https://www.quora.com/How-is-a-UInt64-represented-in-a-32-bit-device-Swift-2-0)
- [Martin R's SO answer to store 64bit Int into UserDefaults](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28177828/7512091)
- [learnappmaking.com](https://learnappmaking.com/userdefaults-swift-setting-getting-data-how-to/#saving-data)
- [codingexplorer.com NSUserDefaults a Swift introduction](https://www.codingexplorer.com/nsuserdefaults-a-swift-introduction/)

Comment: Is this an answer to "Does UserDefaults.integer work on 32-bit platforms?" and "Why doesn't UserDefaults have an instance method like int64(forKey:)?"?

Comment: Thank you, but as @Willeke pointed out, you did not answer my questions.