# Type 'OSType' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject' in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift, swift2, xcode7, avcaptureoutput

I just updated to Xcode 7 beta with Swift 2.0.
And when I updated my project to Swift 2.0, I got this error: "Type 'OSType' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject' in Swift 2.0". My project works perfectly in Swift 1.2. And here is the code got error:

```
videoDataOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
        // create a queue to run the capture on
        var captureQueue=dispatch_queue_create("catpureQueue", nil);
        videoDataOutput?.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: captureQueue)

        // configure the pixel format            
        **videoDataOutput?.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA]** // ERROR here!

        if captureSession!.canAddOutput(videoDataOutput) {
            captureSession!.addOutput(videoDataOutput)
        }
```

I tried to convert kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA to AnyObject but it didn't work. Anyone could help me?
Sorry for my bad English! Thankyou!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is the `kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA` definition in **Swift 1.2**:

```
var kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA: Int { get } /* 32 bit BGRA */
```

This is its definition in **Swift 2.0**:

```
var kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA: OSType { get } /* 32 bit BGRA */
```

Actually the `OSType` is a `UInt32` which can't implicit convert to a `NSNumber`:

> When you write `let ao: AnyObject = Int(1)`, it isn’t really putting an Int into an AnyObject. Instead, it’s implicitly converting your Int into an NSNumber, which is a class, and then putting that in.
>
> https://stackoverflow.com/a/28920350/907422

So try this:

```
videoDataOutput?.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: Int(kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)]
```

or

```
videoDataOutput?.videoSettings = [kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)
```

Comment: That solves indeed the problem. But your answer would be even more helpful with an *explanation* why this is necessary, in particular since OP's code worked in Swift 1.2.

Comment: @MartinR Hello, I have updated my answer… I hope that it can explain more clearly.

Comment: Thank you much! I am recoding an old app to swift (3) and was stuck on this for longer than I'd like to admit.