# Converting Swift array of [Int64] into NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, swift, interop

I am trying to convert array of Swift `Int64` into `NSArray` with `NSNumber` values.

```c
@interface A : NSObject
- (void)bar:(NSArray *)tips;
@end
```

Swift class inherits this Objective-C class:

```
class B : A {
    func foo(tips : [Int64]) {
        self.bar(tips)
    }
}
```

Swift code does not compile with the following error:

```
Type '[Int64]' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

How can I convert `[Int64]` into `NSArray` with `NSNumber` instances?

P.S. I tried number of things and could not find a simple way to do this:

```
self.bar(NSArray(array: tips))
self.bar(tips as NSArray)
```

**EDIT**: this question relates does not relate to trying to build new `NSArray` from separate `Int64` objects, but to convert existing array `[Int64]` into `NSArray`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27305855/swift-cast-int64-to-anyobject-for-nsmutablearray

Comment: @DheerajSingh, the question you posted relates to a single element of an array. I am trying to cast the array itself.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Map over it:

```
func foo(tips : [Int64]) {
    bar(tips.map { NSNumber(longLong: $0) })
}
```

This will build a new array, wrapping all `Int64` in `NSNumber`, this new array should be castable to `NSArray` with no problems.