# How to turn UInt64 into an AnyObject?

Tags: ios, swift

```
let time = UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0)
```

I need to turn `time` into an AnyObject so I can use it for one library. How can I do so?

Comment: Wrap an NSNumber around it?

Comment: See for example http://stackoverflow.com/a/27305906/1187415

Comment: @matt This is however not the correct solution. Just wrapping an NSNumber around it is actually very non-swifty. Sad that this was marked as a duplicate as it is NOT. The correct solution here would be to replace AnyObject with Any, which is never mentioned in any of these posts.

Answer (score 2):

You need to box it inside an NSNumber, just the same as in Objective C.

```
let time = UInt64(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000.0)
let obj: AnyObject = NSNumber(unsignedLongLong: time)
```

Comment: I think a better solution would be to replace AnyObject with Any instead, so you can use native swift arrays and collections. Converting to NSNumber is not very swifty.